# WebDriver clicking wrong URLs

Tags: url, selenium, click, webdriver

I am using the latest version of webdriver. While I can select the right links it seems as the wrong links are actually clicked.

Here is some code to use for Google. What it does is simply clicking a result of a Google Search.

```
  @FindBy (id ="ires")
  private WebElement searchResults;

   public void clickResult(int i) {
    initPage();
    List<WebElement> resultLinks = getSearchResultLinks();
    resultLinks.get(2).click();    
  }

  private List<WebElement> getSearchResultLinks (){
    return searchResults.findElements(By.className("l"));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have an error in your `clickResult`, met6hod: you should pass the `i` to the `resultLinks.get`:

```
public void clickResult(int i) {
    initPage();
    List<WebElement> resultLinks = getSearchResultLinks();
    resultLinks.get(i).click();    
  }
```

Another possible problem may be that the list returned by `getSearchResultLinks` is a zero based array, so to get the first search result you have to call `clickResult(0)` and so on. This may be obvious to programmer, but testers may have problems here :)

Comment: Hi the i thing is true this came into the game during testing. However this is not the problem. The indexing isn't the problem either. If I access the href attribute I get the correct link target. However as soon as I call click it clicks somewhere completely different

Comment: If you are using InternetExplorerDriver, there are some issues that may cause this:
 - if zoom is not 100% it may have troubles to click an element
 - if the link is near the edges of the browser window it may have problems clicking on it
 - if link text is too long or have some special characters, it may have troubles clicking on it

What driver are you using? have you tried the Firefox one?